# Algorithm to select best 2 people

Tags: algorithm, feedback

I am a manager of team of six people. All of them are intelligent and competitive. I have to form a sub team of two people. The sub team should work in tandem and all six are eligible to be part of it. On what lines should an algorithm which selects the best two among six should be devised. If we take the case of a feedback system among the peers what should be the parameters?

Can you suggest me any more literature on this problem? Has it already been solved?

Comment: Why not let the members of the group come up with the algorithm themselves?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to turn into code that will be run for many sets of 6 people, outputting the best pair, or are you looking for guidance on a single real-life team of 6 specific people that you manage?

Comment: the outcome of your exercise should be a recommendation engine or an Excel sheet?

Comment: @Thanks all. 6 is an example. Want to  expand it to more. It's both an example we face and also may be a problem for a wider variety of issues. Eg. The sub team may be a scarse resource which many chase and few will get to consume.

Comment: I love algorithms, but this absolutely feels like a case where you should just use your intuition and knowledge of the individual people.  Things like "A & B recently had a messy breakup" will trump anything you can parameterise neatly.

Comment: Thanks J. But looks like research is done on this problem. See Tryer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem that has been researched under the theme "Complex Systems". A Google scholar search resulted in the following document that seems to deal with the problem you are facing.

[On the Expected Performance of Systems with
Complex Interactions Among Components](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/12-4-5.pdf)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Tryer. Actually the problem arose to a friend and cubicle neighbor today. I thought that it should be a game theory kind of problem. Googled and did not find much(may be because I searched the wrong key words). I will try to understand what the paper says and reply. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anand As with many academic papers, the gap between the problem analyzed in the paper and your "real-world" problem may be non-trivial. In any case, if some of the ideas there can be of help in devising some heuristic/rule of thumb, etc., it would have served its purpose.